# Excel - Dynamically select a range from a column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to dynamically select a range to find a minimum date.

My spreadsheet has several column headings which I need to ignore e.g.

**Column A**
Date Text
SomeOther Text
01/01/13
02/02/13
03/03/13

I'm using Min(A3:A5) which yields the correct answer, over time this column  will grow and i'd like to not have to amend the values (A3:A5) each time.  How can I dynamically create the range to insert into the min calculation?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all the remaining rows in column A will contain only dates? Or might there exist other types of data on new rows added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
Min (Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)))
```

it will get all rows bellow a3

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you just want to track the expansion from `A5` downward while looking for the `MIN` value, a lot of formulas are available. Off the top of my head:

`=MIN(OFFSET(A3,,,COUNTA(A:A)-2,))`

Or...

`=MIN(A3:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A),))`

Let us know if any of these helps.